# Set Output Port High Low C

Tags: c, pic, mplab

I'm using MPLAB to compile a program in C using the CCS compiler.

I want to set an output port as high or low using defined ports.

```
#bit portOut1 = PORTC.0
```

So, I want to set my `portOut1` high or low.

I had used 3 ways to do it, but just one had worked. But I'm not satisfied with that.

1: (Doesn't work, why?)

```
portOut1 = output5.value;
```

2: (Doesn't work, why?)

```
output_bit(portOut1,value);
```

3: (Obviously work)

```
output_bit(pin_c0, value);
```

I don't understand why the first and second way doesn't work.

And I don't want to use the third because I don't know what this pin do unless I comment, and I don't think that is a good program practice.

Anyone knows a way to do that? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, `pin_c0` works, but `portOut1` doesn't. Could it be that `portOut1` is assigned from `PORTC.0` which is different from `pin_c0`?

Comment: Why not just do `#define portOut1 pin_c0`?

Comment: It's Works @DrewMcGowen, thaks! Will work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define portOut1 pin_c0
output_bit(portOut1, value)
```