# PIC HiTech C compiler: assign name to individual port pins

Tags: c, pic

I want to assign individual names to each of the digital port pins, for example, of the PORTA pins, I would like to be able to refer to RA0, RA1 etc as RED_LED, BLUE_LED and so on, so I could write the following:

```
RED_LED = 0;
BLUE_LED = 1;
```

Currently I have to use:

```
RA0 = 0;
RA1 = 1;
```

The above works when for example placed in the main() function.

What code do I need to write to do that? I have tried the following:

```
#define RED_LED RA0;
#define RED_LED @ RA0;
volatile bit RED_LED = RA0;
volatile bit RED_LED = @RA0;
```

None of which work - they all produce errors when I try using my aliases in code.

In the pic16f628a.h file that comes with the compiler, the following is defined.

```
// Register: PORTA
volatile unsigned char           PORTA               @ 0x005;
// bit and bitfield definitions
volatile bit RA0                 @ ((unsigned)&PORTA*8)+0;
volatile bit RA1                 @ ((unsigned)&PORTA*8)+1;
volatile bit RA2                 @ ((unsigned)&PORTA*8)+2;
volatile bit RA3                 @ ((unsigned)&PORTA*8)+3;
volatile bit RA4                 @ ((unsigned)&PORTA*8)+4;
volatile bit RA5                 @ ((unsigned)&PORTA*8)+5;
volatile bit RA6                 @ ((unsigned)&PORTA*8)+6;
volatile bit RA7                 @ ((unsigned)&PORTA*8)+7;
```

Comment: Remove the trailing `;` from the first one.

Comment: Thank you Hot Licks! That worked.

Comment: Maybe could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751843/set-output-port-high-low-c

Answer (score 0):

As said by @HotLicks in comments, you have to remove `;`.

If you write `#define RED_LED RA0;` the compiler will change `RED_LED = 0;` for `RA0; = 0;`

The right way is like below:

```
#define RED_LED  RA0
#define BLUE_LED RA1
```

So you can use the code like you want.

```
RED_LED  = 0;
BLUE_LED = 1;
```